# Phalcon php multilingual routing

Tags: php, routes, multilingual, phalcon

Hi I'm new to the php world.
I'm wondering What is the best way to handle multilingual routing ?
I'm starting to create a website with Phalcon php.
I have the following routing structure.

```
    $router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action/:params', array(
            'controller' => 2,
            'action' => 3,
            'params' => 4,
    ));

    $router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action', array(
            'controller' => 2,
            'action' => 3,
    ));

    $router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller', array(
            'controller' => 2,
            'action' => 'index',
    ));

    $router->add('/{language:[a-z]{2}}', array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

My problem is for instance when I go on mywebsite.com/ I want to change my url in the dispatcher like mywebsite.com/en/ or other language. Is it a good practise to handle it in the beforeDispatchLoop ? I seek the best solutions.

```
/**Triggered before entering in the dispatch loop.
 * At this point the dispatcher don't know if the controller or the actions to be executed exist.
 * The Dispatcher only knows the information passed by the Router. 
 * @param Event $event
 * @param Dispatcher $dispatcher
 */
public function beforeDispatchLoop(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
        //$params = $dispatcher->getParams();
        $params = array('language' => 'en');
        $dispatcher->setParams($params);
        return $dispatcher;
}
```

This code doesn't work at all, my url is not change. The url stay mywebsite.com/ and not mywebsite.com/en/
Thanks in advance.

I try one solution above.
The redirect doesn't seems to work. I even try to hard-coded it for test.

```
use Phalcon\Http\Response;

//Obtain the standard eventsManager from the DI
$eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');
$dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();

$eventsManager->attach("dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop",function($event, $dispatcher)
{
     $dispatcher->getDI->get('response')->redirect('/name/en/index/index/');
}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "my url is not change".

Comment: I edit my question. I want to change the url mywebsite.com/ to another according the language param I set. If I set a language param as 'ru' my url should be mywebsite.com/ru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing something. If I understand correctly: you want to redirect users to a valid url if they open a page without specifying a language.

If that's the case you should verify in your event handler whether the language parameter is specified and redirect user to the same url + the default language if its missing. I am also assuming that your `beforeDispatchLoop` is located in your controller, which is also part of the problem, because your route without a language never matches and you never get into that controller. Instead you need to use it as an event handler with the event manager as per the [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events). Here is how you do the whole thing.

```
$di->get('eventsManager')->attach("dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop", function(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
    $params = $dispatcher->getParams();

    // Be careful here, if it matches a valid route without a language it may go into a massive
    // recursion. Really, you probably want to use `beforeExecuteRoute` event or explicitly
    // check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the language part before redirecting here.

    if (!isset($params['language']) {
        $dispatcher->getDI->get('response')->redirect('/en' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        return false;
    }

    return $dispatcher;
});
```

Comment: The redirect doesn't seems to work. I even try to hard-coded it for test. But the structure of the code seems better :)

Comment: As suggested per the comment in the code, did you try changing the `beforeDispatchLoop` to something else?

Comment: I found the mistake : $this->response->redirect('/MyWebsite/cz/index/index', true); works better don't ask me why.
Thank you so much I was stuck with this issue. Now I can go further.
Also I let it in BeforeDispatchloop :)